# Cleaning nested dynamic MovieClip(Class) in a MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, resource-cleanup

I'm trying to do a cleaning of some classes that is added into a MovieClip, but I can't seems to set the MovieClip(Class) to null. What is the proper way to do it?

```
private var mcHolder:MovieClip = new MovieClip()
    private var mcClass:MovieClip

    private function someFunction():void
    {
        mcClass = new SomeClass()
        mcHolder.addChild(mcClass)
    }

    private function clean():void
    {
        i = mcHolder.numChildren
        if (i > 0)
        {
            while (i--)
            {
                MovieClip(mcHolder.getChildAt(i)).clean()
                **MovieClip(mcHolder.getChildAt(i)) = null**
                mcHolder.removeChild(MovieClip(mcHolder.getChildAt(i)))
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the child movie clips using the removeChildAt() method and don't set any nulls manually.

```
    private function clean():void
    {
        while (mcHolder.numChildren > 0)
        {
           mcHolder.removeChildAt(0);
        }
    }
```